# AWS Lambda function to Retrieve a DynamoDB column by passing primary key as a parameter

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to retrieve values from DynamoDB when passing the primary partition key as the parameters in the URL.

I have a table with two columns:

- movie id
- movie name.

I want to be able to pass the movie id in the URL and to get the correspondent movie as a result. I have already created following lambda function and connected it to an API and DynamoDB.

I am not able to figure out the piece of code to use in order to retrieve the movie name when passing movie id as a parameter

Here is my code so far:

```js
console.log('Loading function');

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-2'});

exports.handler =  function(event, context,callback) {

    var params = {
        TableName: 'movie',
        Key: {

            "movieID": 5,
        }
    }


    docClient.get(params, function(err, data){
    if(err){
        callback(err,null);
        }else{
            callback(null, data);
        }
    })

};
```

Comment: Let's set up Lambda proxy integration - ex: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    var params = {
        TableName: 'movie',
        Key: {

            "movieID": 5,
        },

         AttributesToGet= [
           "movie_name"
        ],
        ProjectionExpression: 'movie_name"
    }
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html

**AttributesToGet** is a legacy field as per documentation and **ProjectionExpression** should be used instead.

Comment: I used above as suggested but I am getting error. Not even allowing me to run the code. Can you share how the complete code should look like please? Also, Should I be changing the key part. I don't  think I should be hard coding it like that. I was thinking getItem might work.